# Jetpack Navigation NavigationDrawer, Custom action for menu item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using jetpack navigation with NavigationDrawer in my app.

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/nav_menu">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/reportsFragment"
        android:title="@string/trip_reports"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_reports"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/messagesFragment"
        android:title="@string/messages"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_chat"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navItemLogout"
        android:title="@string/log_out"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_logout"/>
</group>
```

**In Activity/onCreate**

```
  navigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
  NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavView, navController)
```

All menu items connected to fragments except one. `navItemLogout` has specific action instead of direction.
adding listener,

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            if (it.itemId==R.id.navItemLogout){
                mainActivityViewModel.repository.logout()
            }
            true
        }
```

seems to override the previous setup. So is the only way to proper way to solve my case is to use `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` for all drawer items interaction? Or is this possible to solve this with navController setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call **`NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected()`** to trigger the default listener.
Something like:

```
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
       if (it.itemId==R.id.navItemLogout){
            mainActivityViewModel.repository.logout()
            true
        }

        NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(it, navController)
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        true
    }
```